# Reusing same scripts in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have same form in different pages. In that I have hidden field that value is got from script, on form submit.  I'm trigger that script on submit button on click, all submit button ids are different in different pages. how can I need to reuse same script for all pages?

```
 $('#submit').click(function (e) {
    // place content into form hidden field.
    // I need this code to be reused.
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, make sure that submit button ids are the same on the pages where you use the script.

Comment: Where in your code is your script located?

Comment: @SRack Now script are in page.html.erb

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm asking if there is way to reuse part of script in rails.

Comment: @HarishRamesh: why can't you reuse it now? Because button ids are different? Make it so that they are not different. Thus achieving reusability of your script.

Comment: @HarishRamesh: alternatively, you could _change_ the script, so that it's able to detect and work with your existing buttons, despite their changing ids. But this would be reusing _buttons_, not the script. :)

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is to use a class instead of an id as the selector. That way you can add a behavior to elements by just adding the class.

Answer (score 0):

If the buttons are across multiple pages, it sounds like the script should be in the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization).

Have a read up, but generally this will mean your script will sit in a javascript file under `app/assets/javascripts`, and this code will be available to the views.

Therefore, if you have buttons in different views with the id `submit`, this code will be applied to them all.

Consider changing the selector to a class prefixed with `js-` (i.e. `js-submit`) to clarify the targeting. This will save some pain further down the line.

Have a look at this and see how you get on - any questions, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Using ID's as selectors is in many ways an anti-pattern as it leads to writing "page specific" javascript which leads to duplication as in the end you will want to enhance the behavior of multiple pages or even multiple elements on the same page.

A better approach is to use classes as selectors and think of your javascript as modules that enhance the behaviour of a specific element.

Some key techniques to make your JS suck less:

- Place your javascript in `app/assets/javascripts`.
- Use attributes such as data-attributes on the element to pass input to your handlers.
- Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate handlers instead non-impotent handlers such as `.click` etc. This is vital if you want your JS to work properly with Turbolinks.
- Ensure that your handlers clean up after themselves and do not have unintended side-effects.